# Loop wordpress com div coloridas

Tags: wordpress, loop

bom dia! 
Estou criando um site de uma academia onde tem um menu de modalidades.
Fiz um custom post no wp para criar as modalidades, mais meu problema está na hora de chamar as modalidades, pois cada modalidade tem um cor especifica.

Exemplo: Jiujitsu = box preto | Musculação = Box Laranja e por ai vai.

Segue a imagem de como o meu loop teria que lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu loop está trazendo todas modalidades, mais a div está apenas com 1 cor.

Segue o codigo do meu loop:

```
<article class="col-sm-8 modalidades-total"> 
        <?php 
                            $query_modalidades = array( 'post_type' => 'Modalidade');
                            $modLoop = new WP_Query( $query_modalidades ); 

                            while ($modLoop->have_posts()) : $modLoop->the_post();
                            $id = get_the_ID();
                            ?>             
            <h1><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo $id; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>                
           <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="collapse modalidades-content" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2 menu-modalidades">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Professores</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Horários</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <figure><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive center-block' ) ); } ?></figure>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h2>Sobre</h2>
                                <p><?php the_field('sobre'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h2>Caracteristicas</h2>
                                <p><?php the_field('caracteristicas'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h2>Treinadores</h2>
                                <p><?php the_field('treinadores'); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h2>Investimento</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </article>
```

como listado na imagem, cada modalidade tem sua cor especifica! alguém poderia me da um help ai nesse loop?

Comment: Porque você não categoriza as modalidades e dá uma cor para cada uma delas?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius é uma opção, mais não quero fazer as modalidades de categorias, por isso criei um custom post. Porque iria criar um "post" Jiu-jitsu na categoria lutas, mais ai muay thai iria ficar da mesma cor que jiu-jitsu, ai não dá certo! Por isso não tem como categorizar!

Comment: Se não pode ser por categoria, se puder ser manual, pega cada ID de post e aplica um cor diferente. Se tiver que ser dinâmico, ainda não pensei, MAS, o que poderia fazer era sortear cores para colorir cada post e evitar que elas se repitam.

Comment: @LucianoOliveiraLima, conseguiu resolver esse problema?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira fiz de uma maneira statica mesmo! não consegui resolver!

Comment: Eu tive que implementar algo parecido semana passada. Vou montar uma resposta e postar

Comment: Adiciona um custom field ao post e que recebe uma cor em hexadecimal.